# How to print out the command used to execute code without executing it in Python

Tags: python

I'm intermediate level, so this may be an easy question, but I have no idea how to word it correctly, so sorry in advance.

I am trying to show what command leads to what output, and print all of that out. So an example: numpy.arange(2) prints out an array and I want to use a print statement to say:
numpy.arange(2) 'prints' array
where array would be the actual array

So my code is:

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d)-(\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)')
mo = phoneNumRegex.search('My number is 415-555-4242.')
for i in range(1,3):
    y = str(mo.group(i))
    x = mo.group(i)
    print y + "outputs" + x
```

And so my goal is to say that 'mo.group(1) outputs' and whatever the output of that is, then 'mo.group(2) outputs' and whatever that output is. The actual outputs don't matter, but I want the mo.group(i) to take the value i, but not execute it. Whatever code I tried doesn't work for what I am attempting.
Sorry if that's confusing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use str, you are saying "make a string out of the object returned by mo.group(i)".
What you need is this

```
y = "mo.group({:})".format(i)
```

This says "make a string literal object; then use that object's format method to replace {:} with the value of the object i, whatever type that is"

You can take it one step further by doing something like this:

```
print "mo.group({:}) output is : {:}".format(i,x)
```

Which prints the values of i and x and a little text describing it all in one line. "".format() is the prefered way to do this in python > 2.6, and there's lots it can do. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to see what it's capable of.

Comment: haha thanks for the last comment, I caught it right after posting. I have no idea how to format my comments... This was my crappy solution:  

   `for i in range(1,3):    
        y = str(i) + ')'    
        x = mo.group(i)    
        print 'mo.group(' + y + ' outputs ' + x`

Comment: rather than building strings one bit at a time, using format will make your code more legible, more condensed, and more flexible all at the same time, especially if the complexity of your output grows...  `print "mo.group({:}) output is : {:}".format(i,x)` is a little easier to digest, and you can specify types, precision of floating point values, length/alignment/padding of strings, etc.  python 2.7  https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting

Comment: yeah your way is definitely much, much better. I just searched for a way to do it using my knowledge and that was the only thing I could figure out. But now I know about the string formatting stuff so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to be saying `x = type(mo.group(i))` and print that, that will give you the type that `mo.group(i)` returns such as str, int, etc.

Comment: thanks for your response. and I want to specifically write the words 'mo.group(i)' out but I need the for loop to change the i value each time

Comment: Would you mind giving a more detailed example output? I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: hey I got it figured out already. Look at the comment above if you're still curious. thanks!